# Django forms: Combination of HTML form fields and forms.py fields in same model

Tags: python, html, django, forms, python-2.7

My application has a form which requires me to pre-fill certain values in form fields using information extracted from a user's Twitter account after a successful login. Here's what my form looks like after the user has successfully logged in from his/her Twitter account (the 'Name' field is pre-filled with the full name associated with the user's twitter account):

[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Evangelized(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField()
    mobile_no = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length = 10, validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\w{10}$', message='Mobile number should be strictly of 10 digits.')])
    twitter_url = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=128)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('U', 'Unisex/Parody'))
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length = 128)
```

HTML

```
 <form id="evangelized_form" method="post" action="/rango/fillform/">
            NAME: <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "{{user.get_full_name}}"><br>    
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                <b>{{ field.help_text }}</b><br>
                {{ field }}<br><br>
            {% endfor %}


            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

forms.py

```
class EvangelizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #full_name = forms.CharField(help_text="Full Name")
    email = forms.CharField(help_text="Email ID")
    mobile_no = forms.CharField(help_text="Mobile number")
    twitter_url = forms.CharField(help_text="Twitter URL")
    gender = forms.CharField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(
                 choices=Evangelized.GENDER_CHOICES), help_text="Gender", max_length = 128)
```

Note that I have included the `full_name` attribute in my `models.py`, but have excluded it from `forms.py`. I have included the `Name` field in my HTMl page instead as follows:

```
NAME: <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "{{user.get_full_name}}"><br>
```

Thus, `value = "{{user.get_full_name}}"` pre-fills the `Name` field in the form.

views.py

```
def fillform(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EvangelizedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.full_name = request.POST['name']
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            form.errors
    else:
        form = EvangelizedForm()

    context = RequestContext(request,
                           {'request': request,
                            'user': request.user, 'form':form})    

    #return render(request, 'rango/fillform.html', {'form': form, 'context_instance':context})  
    return render_to_response('rango/fillform.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

Now, I want the `Name` field value to be stored in the database just like all other form field values. However, except the `full_name` attribute, all other form attributes get stored in the database on submitting the form.

I think I'm not catching the `Name` form field value from my HTML page in my view properly. Any solutions?

EDIT 1:

Based on the suggestions of a commenter, I made the following changes in `views.py`:

```
def fillform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EvangelizedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)
        else:
            form.errors
    else:
        #form = EvangelizedForm()
        form = EvangelizedForm(initial={'full_name': request.user.get_full_name()})

    context = RequestContext(request,
                           {'request': request,
                            'user': request.user, 'form':form})    

    #return render(request, 'rango/fillform.html', {'form': form, 'context_instance':context})  
    return render_to_response('rango/fillform.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

However, I'm now getting the following error:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'
```

What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: I don't really understand why you don't make `full_name` a field on the form like all the others, and pass the name value as initial data.

Comment: How do I pass the name value that I got from the User object after Twitter login as a default value in 'full_name' attribute in my forms.py?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Twitter though. You're getting the full name from `request.user`, and passing it into the template; you can pass it to the initial data in your else block in exactly the same way: `form = EvangelizedForm(initial={'full_name': request.user.get_full_name()})`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried adding that in my else block but I'm encountering  an error. I have edited my original post to include the error. Do have a look.